# Linq - Add multiple "dynamic" conditions

Tags: linq

**Problem**

I have an IQueryable, and I want to search it based on roles. An user can have multiple roles so I want to be able to add multiple search conditions (one on top of another).

```cs
public void OnGet()
{
    var productionUnits = _context.ProductionUnits;

    IQueryable query = productionUnits;
    if (User.IsInRole(CustomRole.AdministratorUAP1))
    {
        query = productionUnits.Where(c => c.Id == (int)ProductionUnitEnum.UAP1);
    }
    if (User.IsInRole(CustomRole.AdministratorUAP2))
    {
        query = productionUnits.Where(c => c.Id == (int)ProductionUnitEnum.UAP2);
    }
    ...
}
```

**Expected Output**

If the user is in multiple roles, for example UAP1 and UAP2, I want the query to get both of them in the Where clause. Is there any way to achieve this (I know I could do `List.AddRange()`, but I really want to update the query instead). Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would creeate a list of roles for the user and use `Contains` in the query:

```
var roleIds = new List<int>();

if (User.IsInRole(CustomRole.AdministratorUAP1))
{
    roleIds.Add(ProductionUnitEnum.UAP1);
}
if (User.IsInRole(CustomRole.AdministratorUAP2))
{
    roleIds.Add(ProductionUnitEnum.UAP2)
}
var query = productionUnits.Where(c => roleIds.Contains(c.Id));
```

That will add an `IN` clause to your query for those two roles. If you have more than two roles just add them to the list as appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

Each Linq function returns an `IQueryable<>`, so just keep reusing that:

```
IQueryable<T> query = productionUnits;          // note the <T>
if (User.IsInRole(CustomRole.AdministratorUAP1))
    query = query.Where(c => c.Id == (int)ProductionUnitEnum.UAP1);
if (User.IsInRole(CustomRole.AdministratorUAP2))
    query = query.Where(c => c.Id == (int)ProductionUnitEnum.UAP2);
```

> If the user is in multiple roles, for example UAP1 and UAP2

Then your database is fundamentally broken, you're checking those values against a single field: `c.Id`. One number can't be both values at the same time.

Comment: It can if it is a `or ||` condition.

Comment: You can't write an `or` like that though, serial `.Where` are equivalent to `and` only.